# How can I pass the NO-LINE-BREAK argument to base64-encode-region in M-x?

Tags: helm, commands

I'm editing YAML files where I have to frequently encode and decode base64 values in a buffer. `base64-encode-region` and `base64-decode-region` are perfect for this, but very long strings get encoded as multiline base64, breaking the YAML syntax.

According to the description of the command, one can somehow disable this behaviour:

```
base64-encode-region is an interactive built-in function in ‘C source
code’.

(base64-encode-region BEG END &optional NO-LINE-BREAK)

Base64-encode the region between BEG and END.
Return the length of the encoded text.
Optional third argument NO-LINE-BREAK means do not break long lines
into shorter lines.
```

How can I pass this argument when calling the function with `(helm-)M-x`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add this function to your initialization file (either .emacs.d/init.el or .emacs):

```
(defun my/base64-encode-region-no-break ()
  (interactive)
  (base64-encode-region (mark) (point) t))
```

This creates a new command named `my/base64-encode-region-no-break` that you can call with `M-x` or `helm-M-x`.

Answer (score 6):

If you copy the following lisp code to your [init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html) and restart emacs you can call `base64-encode-region` with universal prefix argument <kbd>C-u</kbd> to get the base64 encoded string without linebreaks:

1. Select the region you want to base64 encode
2. Call <kbd>C-u M-x</kbd> `base64-encode-region` <kbd>RET</kbd>

```el
(defun base64-encode-region-prefix-arg (&rest _args)
  "Pass prefix arg as third arg to `base64-encode-region'."
  (interactive "r\nP"))

(advice-add 'base64-encode-region :before #'base64-encode-region-prefix-arg)
```